# Where to accept subscription payments?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

TL;DR If this question doesn't make sense, please check the following video explanation: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9o2KhiBf1lY

I created a Chrome extension and followed the directions here: https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/one_time_payments

[image]
In the drop-down, I changed it to a subscription system with a free trial.

And my Chrome extension successfully uses the License API to check the payment status.

But now I'm wondering:

- Where do my users go to pay for the full version?
- How long is the free trial configured for?

You might be thinking that I have to use the [Payments API](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/payments-iap), but the [documentation says:](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/money#free_trial)

> If the trial is expired, you can direct the user to the web store listing to purchase the item.

Why does it say to direct the user to web store? If I go there, it just says to install the chrome extension, there's no option to pay for it.

And how can it know when the free trial has expired? I never configured a value for it and there's no "free trial duration" specified in the docs.

Meanwhile, the [Payments API](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/payments-iap) makes it clear that it's for in-app purchases with SKUs. If this is the only way to accept payment, what's the purpose of that pricing configuration that I set up above?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Why am I being downvoted on this? If my question isn't clear, please let me know and I can try my best to clarify. The payments system for subscription chrome extensions with a trial is confusing to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have all the answers in the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/one_time_payments#verifying-payment). Read it carefully.

You decide the length of the trial period. In your extension's code, when you check the user's license, it will reveal when your extension was first installed. Compare that with the current date to determine if the user is still within the trial period or not.

The trial and the paid extension are the same, both installed from Chrome's Web Store. If the purchase button doesn't appear to you may be because you are the developer.

In the documentation you have sample code to request the license and check the trial period.

Comment: Sorry, that tells me how to check the license information, which I'm already doing, but my question is, how does the user get prompted to make the payment? How does the developer accept the payment?

The documentation says: "If the trial is expired, you can direct the user to the web store listing to purchase the item."

But there's nothing there indicating that the user can make a purchase.

Comment: It is **your** responsibility to do that: **you** check if the user's trial period is over, **you** prompt the user if that is the case, and **you** supposedly already created a [merchant account](https://payments.google.com) with your banking information where to receive the payments.

Comment: So then you're saying the documentation is faulty when it says to "direct the user to the web store listing to purchase the item", and instead I'm supposed to create an In-App purchase, and use the Payments API? I'm asking how to prompt the user, and your answer is "prompt the user" which doesn't tell me how. If the documentation is faulty and I'm supposed to use the Payments API, you can just say so

Comment: You **don't** have to use the Payments API. You prompt the user in the way it fits best with your extension: an `alert`, a custom dialog, a whole new window, whatever. The user will install and/or subscribe to your extension in Chrome Web Store. If the purchase button doesn't appear to you it may be because the extension is set as private and you access with your own developer account. Have you tried opening your extension's Chrome Web Store entry from a different account?

Comment: Okay, I just tried completely signing out of my Chrome profile and signing into a totally different, unrelated account that has no chrome extensions, on a different computer. Then I installed the extension, but still the webstore doesn't show anywhere to pay for the subscription.

See the following images: https://imgur.com/a/AjlWQ

It says "Offers In-App purchases" because I added an In-App purchase as a workaround to this issue. But if I delete it, it goes away. It never shows in the Webstore where to pay for the extension itself.

Comment: I assume you did what says [here](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/one_time_payments#before-starting). Can you provide a link to the extension in CWS?

Comment: Yes, I followed that guide. I updated the original post with a video showing exactly what I did: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9o2KhiBf1lY also here's the CWS link: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/copiedin/jgiejpldlcmmopmojhhnjgidjcijbbla

Comment: I've sent you an e-mail

Comment: I've marked this as correct because technically it is right, although it didn't directly solve my issue. I have no idea why it wasn't working for me before, but publishing a new extension in the same way is suddenly working as Ivan described. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @IvánNokonoko Hi Ivan, could you please help with my issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55040616/integrate-chrome-extension-with-chrome-web-store-payments ..

Comment: Make sure, logged in gmail (google chrome) user account is different than what you have used to publish the application.
e.g: if the extension is published from "abc@gmail.com" and you are logged in to the chrome with same account, google will considers you as "Admin/Author" of the extension and will not ask you for the payment.